# Fix a field with characteristic different from 2 in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I did a [proof](https://github.com/rjraya/Isabelle/blob/master/curves/Hales.thy) for elliptic curves taking as a base field the reals.

Now I want to change the reals by an arbitrary field which has characteristic different from 2, so that from the equation 2x = 0 one can deduce that x = 0.

How does one phrase this in a proof assistant like Isabelle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you can use

```
class ell_field = field +
  assumes zero_ne_two: "2 ≠ 0"
```

For example, see [The Group Law for Elliptic Curves by Stefan Berghofer](https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/Elliptic_Curves_Group_Law/document.pdf).

---

I assume that you wish to work with the class `field` from the main library of the object logic HOL. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a general treatment of the ring characteristics in the aforementioned library (hopefully, if it does exist, someone will point it out for us). Therefore, I devised my own definitional framework to give this answer a context:

```
context semiring_1
begin

definition characteristic :: "'a itself ⇒ nat" where
  "characteristic a = 
    (if (∃n. n ≥ 1 ∧ of_nat n = 0) 
    then (LEAST n. n ≥ 1 ∧ of_nat n = 0) 
    else 0)"

end

class ell_field = field +
  assumes zero_ne_two: "2 ≠ 0"
begin

lemma x2: "2 * x = 0 ⟹ x = 0"
  by (simp add: zero_ne_two)

lemma "characteristic TYPE('a) ≠ 2"
proof(rule ccontr, simp)
  assume c2: "characteristic TYPE('a) = 2"
  define P where "P = (λn. (n ≥ 1 ∧ of_nat n = 0))" 
  from c2 have ex: "∃n. P n" 
    unfolding P_def characteristic_def by presburger
  with c2 have least_2: "(LEAST n. P n) = 2"
    unfolding characteristic_def P_def by auto
  from LeastI2_ex[OF ex, of P] have "P (LEAST n. P n)" by simp
  then have "2 = 0" unfolding least_2 unfolding P_def by simp
  with zero_ne_two show False by simp
qed

end
```

Comment: There's really no reason to define this `multiple` constant. You can just use `of_nat`. The definition also generalises to `semiring_1`. In addition to that, you can express the characteristic more succinctly with `Gcd` like this: `definition characteristic :: "'a itself ⇒ nat" where "characteristic _ = Gcd {n. n > 0 ∧ of_nat n = 0}"`

Comment: That should be equivalent if I haven't missed anything, and you get the edge case 0 for free since `Gcd {} = 0`. However, if you only need to talk about non-characteristic-2 fields, it is certainly easier to just use `2 ≠ 0` as Stefan Berghofer did.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Thank you for your comments. I updated the second part of my answer. I was looking for the equivalent of `power` (that is interpreted in `class.monoid_mult`) for `class.monoid_add`, but I could not find it. It did not occur to me that it is not defined until the introduction of semirings. In my view, from the perspective of software engineering, this is a strangely assymetric library design decision. Somehow, it would be nice to be able to define power once for `monoid` and then interpret it as multiple for `monoid_add` and power for `monoid_mult`.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Also, of course, it is best to use `Gcd` instead of `if/LEAST` but the Isabelle code in the second part of the answer is meant to be seen as a substitute for informal reasoning (it is not meant to be added in any given Isabelle theory) and I do not wish to change the proof.

Comment: There is a power operation on monoids in `HOL-Algebra`, which is more geared towards abstract algebra. The `monoid_add`/`monoid_mult` classes are a bit more pragmatic and oriented towards the concrete instances that you want to get out in the end (nat, int, rat, real, complex, etc.). I'm not sure there would be much of a concrete tangible benefit of introducing a more general power operation in a type class.